# Why does my Azure deploy say my empty MVC 4 app is too large for extra small?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, deployment, azure

I'm going through the tutorials on Azure with an empty MVC 4 Basic project.

I set my VM size to extra small, and resized my Local Storage-> Diagnostics to 100mb, yet I still get the error:

```
Validation Errors: Total requested resources are too large for the specified VM size
```

I have a hard time believing that an empty MVC 4 project is more than 20gb.  Any ideas what is going on here?

Comment: You are sure you localstorage drives are less than 20,000 in space altogether ? Also in Cloud configuration and All Configuration ?

Comment: I deleted and re-added my local storage Diagnostics and it appears to be working now.

Comment: Good to hear ;) @Scottie

Comment: @Scottie - please post that comment as an answer (and mark it as such).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted and re-added my local storage Diagnostics and it appears to be working now.